# How to retrieve portfolio AUM from xbbg

Tags: python, bloomberg

When I am trying to retrieve my portfolio's AUM/mkt value from bloomberg xbbg package, I am unable to do so, only able to obtain data from its equities with

```
blp.bds(client_id,flds='Portfolio_Data',use_port=True, Reference_Date = '20210101')
```

This command returns only the securities and positions, and does not display total amount within the portfolio (which includes the cash)

Comment: Hello, did you find a solution for this? Thanks. I am also trying to retrieve everything there is in the portfolio.